# How to serialize/deserialize json with nested field in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, json-deserialization

I am using `Json.decodeFromString<User>("json string")` (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md)

model is like

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String, val assets: List<Asset>)
data class Asset(val id: String, val sku: String, val name: String)
```

but input json is like

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "userId",
    "name": "userName",
    "body": {
      "assets": [
        {
          "data": {
            "id": "assetId",
            "sku": "assetSku",
            "name": "assetName"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I parse json with serializer? Seems not able to parse with delegate and surrogate serializers easily.

Comment: Your data classes are wrong, with this schema, you'll need five data classes, see the below answer, it has all the data classes you need to parse this JSON, you can obviously go without using `SerializedName` by naming the variables same as in JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#under-the-hood-experimental

Tried something like this:

```
@Serializable(with = AssetSerializer::class)
data class Asset(val id: String, val sku: String, val name: String)

@Serializable(with = UserSerializer::class)
data class User(val id: String, val name: String, val assets: List<Asset>)

object AssetSerializer: KSerializer<Asset> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
    buildClassSerialDescriptor("Asset") {
        element("data", buildClassSerialDescriptor("data") {
            element("id", String.serializer().descriptor)
            element("sku", String.serializer().descriptor)
            element("name", String.serializer().descriptor)
        })
    }
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Asset) {
        require(encoder is JsonEncoder)
        encoder.encodeJsonElement(buildJsonObject {
            put("data", buildJsonObject {
                put("id", value.id)
                put("sku", value.sku)
                put("name", value.name)
            })
        })
    }
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Asset {
        require(decoder is JsonDecoder)
        val root = decoder.decodeJsonElement()
        val element = root.jsonObject["data"]!!
        return Asset(
            id = element.jsonObject["id"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
            sku = element.jsonObject["sku"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
            name = element.jsonObject["name"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
        )
    }
}

object UserSerializer: KSerializer<User> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
    buildClassSerialDescriptor("User") {
        element("data", buildClassSerialDescriptor("data") {
            element("id", String.serializer().descriptor)
            element("name", String.serializer().descriptor)
            element("body", buildClassSerialDescriptor("body") {
                element("assets", ListSerializer(Asset.serializer()).descriptor)
            })
        })
    }
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: User) {
        require(encoder is JsonEncoder)
        encoder.encodeJsonElement(buildJsonObject {
            put("data", buildJsonObject {
                put("id", value.id)
                put("name", value.name)
                put("body", buildJsonObject {
                    put("assets", JsonArray(value.assets.map { asset ->
                        encoder.json.encodeToJsonElement(asset)
                    }))
                })
            })
        })
    }
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): User {
        require(decoder is JsonDecoder)
        val root = decoder.decodeJsonElement()
        val element = root.jsonObject["data"]!!
        val assets = element
            .jsonObject["body"]!!
            .jsonObject["assets"]!!
            .jsonArray
            .map { asset ->
                decoder.json.decodeFromJsonElement(asset)
            }

        return Asset(
            id = element.jsonObject["id"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
            name = element.jsonObject["name"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
            assets = assets,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) seems to be wrong , every field needs to have name corresponding to json value , or use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)'s `SerializedName` annotation and Parse sing Gson.

Your User POJO should look something like this,

```
data class User (

   @SerializedName("data") var data : UserData

)
data class UserData(

   @SerializedName("id") var id : String,
   @SerializedName("name") var name : String,
   @SerializedName("body") var body : Body

)
data class Body (

   @SerializedName("assets") var assets : List<Assets>

)
data class Assets (

   @SerializedName("data") var data : AssetsData

)
data class AssetsData(

   @SerializedName("id") var id : String,
   @SerializedName("sku") var sku : String,
   @SerializedName("name") var name : String

)
```

for serializing and deserializing

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
}
```

```
val gson = Gson()
val jsonValue = gson.toJson(User)

val jsonToUser = gson.fromJson(jsonValue ,User::class.java)
```

Comment: Totally understand, but the reality is, we only have two models, which would interact with other components. The only question is how to serialize/deserialize them into/from a predefined json schema.

Comment: @Mike See the updated ans , if it helps

Comment: this of topic, the answer is about Kotlinx Json, not Google Gson